# Using serif fonts instead of sans fonts based on a class file

Tags: fonts, errors

There is a class file [here](https://github.com/CiaranWelsh/WafergenPaper/blob/master/wiley-article.cls) for a journal. The default font is `lato`. I would like to use `lmodern` as both text and math fonts. I changed some commands to get this, but I get scalable font and missing glyph errors. The file is too complex for me. I'm using pdflatex. How do I get `lmodern` font?

Comment: Are you planning on submitting to the journal, or do you just like their style? If the former, then you're just  making work for yourself - and for them when they fix your submission to get it back to their standard

Comment: I'm planning to submit the journal, actually. I thought the conversion should be simple and tried. But I could not get what I thought.

Comment: It's also probably pointless. Their journal, their fonts

Comment: If you're submitting to a journal, and you make changes that don't conform to their style, there are two likely outcomes:  They might return it to you for changes, or they may change it themselves.  In the second case, don't expect the changes to be error free, and you may not get an adequate opportunity to make corrections.  Don't take the chance.